# Cross-platform way to open a file using Java 1.5

Tags: java, linux, file-association, java-5

I'm using Java 1.5 and I'd like to launch the associated application to open the file. I know that Java 1.6 introduced the [Desktop API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/), but I need a solution for **Java 1.5**.

So far I found a way to do it in Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "rundll32", 
                          "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", fileName });
```

Is there a cross-platform way to do it? Or at least a similar solution for **Linux**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

+1 for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325299/#325517)

Additionally I would suggest the following implementation using polymorphism:

This way you can add new platform easier by reducing coupling among classes.

*The Client code:*

```
 Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

 desktop.open( aFile );
 desktop.imaginaryAction( aFile );
```

*The Desktop impl:*

```
package your.pack.name;

import java.io.File;

public class Desktop{

    // hide the constructor.
    Desktop(){}

    // Created the appropriate instance
    public static Desktop getDesktop(){

        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        Desktop desktop = new Desktop();
         // This uf/elseif/else code is used only once: here
        if ( os.indexOf("windows") != -1 || os.indexOf("nt") != -1){

            desktop = new WindowsDesktop();

        } else if ( os.equals("windows 95") || os.equals("windows 98") ){

            desktop = new Windows9xDesktop();

        } else if ( os.indexOf("mac") != -1 ) {

            desktop = new OSXDesktop();

        } else if ( os.indexOf("linux") != -1 && isGnome() ) {

            desktop = new GnomeDesktop();

        } else if ( os.indexOf("linux") != -1 && isKde() ) {

            desktop = new KdeDesktop();

        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("The platform %s is not supported ",os) );
        }
        return desktop;
    }

    // default implementation :( 
    public void open( File file ){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // default implementation :( 
    public void imaginaryAction( File file  ){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

// One subclass per platform below:
// Each one knows how to handle its own platform   


class GnomeDesktop extends Desktop{

    public void open( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: execute gnome-open <file>
    }

    public void imaginaryAction( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec:gnome-something-else <file>
    }

}
class KdeDesktop extends Desktop{

    public void open( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: kfmclient exec <file>
    }

    public void imaginaryAction( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: kfm-imaginary.sh  <file>
    }
}
class OSXDesktop extends Desktop{

    public void open( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: open <file>
    }

    public void imaginaryAction( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: wow!! <file>
    }
}
class WindowsDesktop extends Desktop{

    public void open( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: cmd /c start <file>
    }

    public void imaginaryAction( File file ){
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec: ipconfig /relese /c/d/e
    }
}
class Windows9xDesktop extends Desktop{

    public void open( File file ){
        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec: command.com /C start <file>
    }

    public void imaginaryAction( File file){
       //Runtime.getRuntime().exec: command.com /C otherCommandHere <file>
    }
}
```

This is only an example, in real life is not worth to create a new class only to parametrize a value ( the command string %s )  But let's do imagine that each method performs another steps in platform specific way.

Doing this kind of approach, may remove unneeded if/elseif/else constructs that with time may introduce bugs ( if there are 6 of these in the code and a change is neede, you may forget to update one of them, or by copy/pasting you may forget to change the command to execute)

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki you fail to explain why you think it is not a solution, that way, people reading this answer may evaluate  whether to use it or not.

Comment: You didn't show any code that actually works and opens default browser for java 1.5, just some skeleton for it without any usefull implementation, it is why this is not a solution.

Answer (score 13):

```
public static boolean isWindows() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    return os.indexOf("windows") != -1 || os.indexOf("nt") != -1;
}
public static boolean isMac() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    return os.indexOf("mac") != -1;
}
public static boolean isLinux() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    return os.indexOf("linux") != -1;
}
public static boolean isWindows9X() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    return os.equals("windows 95") || os.equals("windows 98");
}
```

and

```
 if (isLinux())
  {
     cmds.add(String.format("gnome-open %s", fileName));
     String subCmd = (exec) ? "exec" : "openURL";
     cmds.add(String.format("kfmclient "+subCmd+" %s", fileName));
  }
  else if (isMac())
  {
     cmds.add(String.format("open %s", fileName));
  }
  else if (isWindows() && isWindows9X())
  {
     cmds.add(String.format("command.com /C start %s", fileName));
  }
  else if (isWindows())
  {
     cmds.add(String.format("cmd /c start %s", fileName));
  }
```

Comment: You may also, take polymorphism with that. That way you can add flexibility to the implementation. Then you can avoid another if/elseif/else chain for the next operation.

Comment: You should use `xdg-open` instead of `gnome-open` or `kfmclient` or whatever, so it works more nicely in xfce or other environments.

Answer (score 12):

[JDIC](http://javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/) is a library that provides Desktop-like functionality in Java 1.5.

Comment: This library seems to solve the problem. I don't understand why people voted up for reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 5):

Just as an addition: Rather than `gnome-open`, use `xdg-open`. It's part of the [XdgUtils](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/), which are in turn part of the LSB Desktop support package (starting with 3.2).

You can (should) still use `gnome-open` as a fallback, but `xdg-open` will also work on non-GNOME desktops.

Comment: Great addition. I was not aware of this package.

Answer (score 4):

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) gives you the possibility to lokk for the standard program to open a file via:

```
final Program p = Program.findProgram(fileExtension);
p.execute(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Strictly this isn't Cross-Platform since SWT is platform dependent, but for every platform you can use a diffenrent SWT jar.

Comment: Note: the source of Program.java are here http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/program/Program.java.htm . May be that can help too

Comment: Probably this is very useful for Java 1.5 + SWT users. But using SWT for only this might not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OS default way to open it for you.

- Windows: "cmd /c *fileName*
- Linux w/gnome "gnome-open *filename*"
- Linux w/Kde ??
- OSx "open *filename*"

Answer (score 0):

Another answer (by boutta) suggests using SWT. I wouldn't recommend referencing the library for this purpose only, but if you are using it already, simply execute:

```
Program.launch("http://google.com/");
```

Take note that this method will only work (and return `true`) if a `Display` object has already been created (for instance by creating a `Shell`). Also take note that it must run in the main thread; e.g.:

```
Display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Program.launch("http://google.com/");
    }
});
```

In the example above I've launched a URL, but launching files works in the same way.

Answer (score -3):

We do put the command outside somewhere in the configuration file.

Your "JAR and source code" will be "cross-platform", but your deployment doesn't.

You can also do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325299/cross-platform-way-to-open-a-file-using-java-15#326360). You can put the classname of the factory class of the "Deskop" implementation into the setup file. (may be guide or spring, if you like)