# Open a file with an external application on Java

Tags: java, external-application

How do you open a file from a java application when you do not know which application the file is associated with. Also, because I'm using Java, I'd prefer a platform independent solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With JDK1.6, the [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class can be useful.

```
public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(document);
}
```

Comment: Is this piece of code also works on linux?

Comment: Yes ... but it is a good idea to call  `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` or `Desktop.isSupported(action)` first, see the Javadoc.

Answer (score 5):

```
File file
Desktop.getDesktop().open( file );
```

Since Java 1.6

Previous to that you could [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325299)

*Summary*

It would look something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( getCommand( file ) );

public String getCommand( String file ){ 
    // Depending on the platform could be
    //String.format("gnome-open %s", fileName)
    //String.format("open %s", fileName)
    //String.format("cmd /c start %s", fileName)
    // etc. 
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add "xdg-open" (http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) for a more integrated Linux-command that isn't available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could hack something together with a bat file on Windows and equivalent on Unix, but that wouldn't be that fun.

I think your best bet would be the [JDesktop Integration Components (JDIC)](https://jdic.dev.java.net/).  In particular, the [Desktop](https://jdic.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/javadoc/jdic/org/jdesktop/jdic/desktop/Desktop.html) class has exactly the method you're looking for.

EDIT: Apparently, I'm behind the times because this has been integrated into Java 1.6. In any case, if you're working in an earlier Java, it may still be useful.

Comment: The links provided are broken. You need to fix both. Thanks.