# How to open (as in launch) text file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, launch

My program has the following code where `output` is a StringBuilder:

```
   try
   {
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"));
       bw.write(output.toString());
   }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
       System.out.println("File error: "+e.getMessage());
   }
```

after the `bw.write(output.toString());` I want to have another line that launches the textfile with the default application. I considered using the desktop API but heard it has bad cross-platform compatibility. Any suggestions?

Comment: Launch a text file? You mean opening it with the OS specific menu?

Comment: I mean mean opening it with the OS specific applicaon. e.g. notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a file with an external application on Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390736/open-a-file-with-an-external-application-on-java)?

Comment: So I use desktop api.  I haven't had any issues cross-platform.  You can't specify the application opening your text file though. Edit: so I looked and it has some problems across different linux environments.  Do you need to handle so many edge cases?

Comment: got it working with Desktop api, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

```
File file = new File("somefile.txt");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(file);
```

I think you were looking for this.

Comment: could this be done all in one line? `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("somefile.txt"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Main m = new Main();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Main() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
}
```

Worked for me

Comment: The OP asked for opening the file. `Desktop.getDesktop().open` would be more suitable.