# Java: Open a file (Windows + Mac)

Tags: java, file, pdf, multiplatform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to launch the default (native) application for a given file from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560077/how-to-launch-the-default-native-application-for-a-given-file-from-java)

I have a java application that opens a file. This works perfect on windows, but not on mac.

The problem here is that I use the windows configuration to open it. The code is:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file);`

Now my question is what is the code to open it in mac? Or is there another way to open a PDF that works multi platform?

**EDIT:**

I created the file as followed:

```
File folder = new File("./files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

in a loop i add them to an array:

`fileArray.add(listOfFiles[i]);`

If i try to open a file from that array with Desktop.getDesktop().open(file), it says it can't find that file (the path is messed up because I used './files' as folder)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an OperatingSystem Detector:

```
public class OSDetector
{
    private static boolean isWindows = false;
    private static boolean isLinux = false;
    private static boolean isMac = false;

    static
    {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        isWindows = os.contains("win");
        isLinux = os.contains("nux") || os.contains("nix");
        isMac = os.contains("mac");
    }

    public static boolean isWindows() { return isWindows; }
    public static boolean isLinux() { return isLinux; }
    public static boolean isMac() { return isMac; };

}
```

Then you can open files like this:

```
public static boolean open(File file)
{
    try
    {
        if (OSDetector.isWindows())
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
            {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
             file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else if (OSDetector.isLinux() || OSDetector.isMac())
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open",
                                                   file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else
        {
            // Unknown OS, try with desktop
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
            {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Answer to your edit:

Try to use `file.getAbsoluteFile()` or even `file.getCanonicalFile()`.

Comment: Why you are using the `String[]` variant of `exec` on Linux/OS X, but not for Windows?

Comment: Martin, Just tested this on one of my older macs, on there it doesn't work. It says `UnsupportedClassVersion `. Should I use another thing for that?

Comment: I changed the condition for Mac in the OS Detecter, try again, please.

Comment: Ironically, the `toLowercase()` should be `toLowerCase()`, but it won't let me edit your post. Also, for windows you should separate the rundll and the rest thus: `"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler"`, the way you wrote it produces an error because there is no `"rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler.exe"`

Answer (score 15):

At first, anything related to *.dll is windows-ish.

Perhaps you could try the code below for Linux, it can possibly also work on MAC:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();  
d.open(new File("foo.pdf"))
```

Comment: I does work on Mac OS X.

Comment: d being what kind of object when you declare it?

Comment: Btw, I've tried this one, it gives the error it can't find my variable. Note the edit in my question, you can see how I created the file.

Comment: @Mi Mee: Since he didn't know what `d` was, I edited your answer a little bit to help to OP.

Comment: Also call `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()`, just to be safe. And keep in mind that it's only java 6.

Comment: Mine is desktop supported. The only problem is that I have found the folder by looking for a map in the currentdir (./) and now it adds that to the url, It should work by my knowledge but it says it can't find the file.

Comment: could you make sure that File was initialized with a full path?

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked for me on Mac and Windows 10

Comment: worked on ubuntu 16

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the command [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) so have

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open " + file);
```

---

*Edit by Martijn*
This is better, when you use spaces in your file path:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open", file.getAbsolutePath()});
```

Comment: When I run this it gives an IOException `Cannot run program "open": Can't find given file". However the code in my question works like a charm.

Comment: Try with the full path of open

Comment: How will I know the full path of open? it has to work on multi platform, isn't the open located different on every OS?

Comment: You've got my +1, it's working on Mac OS X.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the system is mac or windows? I'm testing it out on windows atm, since it should work on both platforms.