# How to open a file after clicking the open button in jFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here is my jFileChooser swing code which opens another window after clicking the open button. Then we need to select the corresponding file in the second window in-order to actually open that file. I need to to do all the operations on the first window itself.

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
/*
 * Created by JFormDesigner on Tue Sep 22 13:24:36 IST 2015
 */



/**
 * @author Avinash Raj
 */
public class FileChooser extends JFrame {
    private JFileChooser fileChooser1;
    public FileChooser() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void fileChooser1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int returnVal = fileChooser1.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            //File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            setVisible(false);
            String path=fileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            String filename=fileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getName();
            //This is where a real application would open the file.

            System.out.println("Opening: " + path + "\n");
            CSVReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path), ',', '\'', 1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String [] nextLine;
            try {
                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                    int no_cols = nextLine.length;
                    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2] );
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user." + "\n");
        }
    }



    private void initComponents() {
      fileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(700,500);

        fileChooser1.addActionListener(e -> fileChooser1ActionPerformed(e));
        fileChooser1.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "csv files only", "csv");
        fileChooser1.setFileFilter(filter);
        add(fileChooser1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());

    }


    public  static  void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                FileChooser f = new FileChooser();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560077/how-to-launch-the-default-native-application-for-a-given-file-from-java

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024031/java-open-a-file-windows-mac

Comment: I'm trying to choose a particular file using jFilechooser.

Comment: Llike [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually don't embed the chooser in the top-level Frame or add an action listener, instead I add a button or menu option to the frame to trigger when to show the chooser, then wait for showOpenDialog() to return and then call getSelectedFile().

What I usually do is this:

```
public class MyJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MyJFrame() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("open file");
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            selectFile();
        });
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void selectFile() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        // optionally set chooser options ...
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            // read  and/or display the file somehow. ....
        } else {
            // user changed their mind
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have the file reference and you are working with Java 1.6 or above, you can use [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class:

And you can use the following command to do what you want (of course, your file would be opened with the default application):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(yourSelectedFile);
```

Remember that "`yourSelectedFile`" is [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) type.

Hope it helps and this is what you want to achieve.

Happy coding.