# How to retrieve and view file in database using java

Tags: java, postgresql, file, upload

I have developed a application where users can upload and download files. My question is how to store these files in a remote database(Postgresql) and retrieve it.

in localhost ,Saving "file Path" in database I was able to save and view files.
Since I am accessing remote database and different users upload files instead of saving using file Path, I saved files in bytea type. Now I am confuse how to convert binary format in to a File and view it

> Now

```
CREATE TABLE upload_file
 (
 regno character varying(20),
 data bytea
  )


public byte[] filet_retrive(String index) {
    try {

        byte[] fileBytes;
        String query;

        con = new DBConnection().makeConnection();

        query = "select data from upload_file where regno ='" + index + "'";

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            fileBytes = rs.getBytes(1);

            return fileBytes;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbOperations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Earlier working code

```
Statement s=db.DBConnection.makeConnection().createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT file_path from file_upload2 where file_name=\'" + file + "\'");
                    while (rs.next()) {   
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                   // veiw the file
                   open(new File(rs.getString(1)));
                    }


public static boolean open(File file) {
    OSDetector osdetector = new OSDetector();
    try {
        if (osdetector.isWindows()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
                file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else if (osdetector.isLinux() || osdetector.isMac()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open",
                file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else // Unknown OS, try with desktop
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: "Now I am unable to view it." - You might want tell us what problems you are facing, e.g. what you'd expect to happen and what you get instead. You might also want to share how you are storing the files in the database. And while you're at it, can you have a look at the bytes of the original file and those that you get from the db and tell us whether you get differences (use some hex editor or something like that).

Comment: I want to retrieve binary format from remote database and view it. I am not sure how to convert binary format in to File Format

Comment: try `select encode(data,'escape') data from upload_file`

Comment: That depends on what you'd actually like to do. Is it like the second snippet, i.e. you'd pass that data to some external application? In that case write the bytes to a temporary file and pass that to the application. If it's something internal use a ByteArrayInputStream or ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: For me it seems you might want to [launch the native app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024031/java-open-a-file-windows-mac) (on the current OS) for the given file. Is that correct? I'm almost completely sure that you cannot do that if you've got only the file's contents (not the file itself). Maybe you could use some IO redirection, but that will be an OS specific solution; if it works at all. -- You could try to create a temporary file (from its contents & extension from its name) & try to open that instead.

Comment: I have developed a application in some Forms users can upload/ download files. when I run it in localhost (Saving file name in database ) it works. Since users access from different PCs I save uploaded files in bytea Format. Now I want to retrieve these binary format over network and view or download files

Comment: But you already retrieve it. What is your problem then? *Now I am unable to view it* is very vague. If you don't want to launch your OS' native app for these files, what do you want to do with them?