# how to execute the specified exe file

Tags: java

i need to execute  any  file using java program.like in jdk we have java,javac...like that

```
URL url = new URL("http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_116568555");    
    url.openConnection();    
    InputStream reader = url.openStream();    
    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("t1.txt");    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];    
    int bytesRead = 0;    
    while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)    
    {      
       writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       buffer = new byte[153600];
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

   String[] cmd = new String[1];    
  cmd[0]="t1.txt";  
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My        Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\urldemo\\t1.txt");  

p.destroy();  
}  

}
```

here is list of errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Documents": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)  
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)  
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)  
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)  
    at urldemo.Urldemo.main(Urldemo.java:58)  
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:376)  
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)  
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
```

Comment: In your exec call, there should be called a program to open your .txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get over the path problem you'll see that you can't execute a text file on windows, because text files are not executable programs. If you want to *open* the file rather than execute it use the Desktop class. See for example [How to launch the default (native) application for a given file from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560077/how-to-launch-the-default-native-application-for-a-given-file-from-java)

```
File file = new File ("c:/documents and settings/Intel/whatever/file.txt");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

Comment: and what i have to do if i want to execute the exe file

Comment: First you need an exe file, and it has to be called something.exe and not something.txt

Comment: i know sir.. i have  an exe with the same name and in the same directory,, si i just rename the file extension to .exe... and now plz explain how to execute this exe

Comment: and i am trying your getDesktop method but its showing me error that argument required File but found String

Comment: Oh, that's true, fixed. And the way you execute an exe file in your directory is the same as in any directory: with the code in your question but using the .exe file extension instead of .txt

Comment: and what is to be done to sent this dos prompt(.exe file) in background?

Comment: I think that merits posting a new "question" on this site. Since you can't control the flags that Java passes to CreateProcess you'll have to change the subsystem flag in the .exe from "console" to "windows"

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start notepad C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My        Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\urldemo\\t1.txt");
```

//you can also provide other editor instead of notepad

Comment: bro what i have to do, if i wanna execute an exe in the same directory with the same name??

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My        Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\urldemo\\t1.exe");

Comment: i did this.. but its not working,, firstly my program was to execute an exe but it was not working for me