# How to open all files extensions in java?

Tags: java

I've got a studying project about files managment system app in java(client-server- like google drive).
One of the features is to open file. you click on a file and it should open.
examples of files, doc,exe,txt,jpg.

My question is how do I do it in java? I know how to read/write from txt. but I need a generic code for all kinds of files..

Comment: What do you mean by "open file"? Do you want to [launch the default (native) application for a given file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560077/how-to-launch-the-default-native-application-for-a-given-file-from-java)?

Comment: yes. lets say a word file- doc.. openning it will open as well the word app.